# Refresh or reload sidebar when google sheet cell edit

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar

I have google sheet and data drop-down on Cell C4. and I made custom sidebar with several input fields. What I want is to refresh or reload sidebar when I choose data on Cell C4 through drop-down. Plz, tell me your great Idea!

+++

value= is from C4. when user change the value of C4, I want to refresh sidebar or input field automatically to update input field with current value of C4.

```js
function showsidbar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("main.html").evaluate();  //createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
 
   html.setTitle('입력창입니다!')
    //  .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}

function include(filename){
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}



function bb(){
  var mainsheet = "기본";
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var targetSheet = sheet.getSheetByName(mainsheet);
  var value = targetSheet.getRange("N5").getValue();
   return value;;
   }

function Name(){
  var mainsheet = "기본";
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var targetSheet = sheet.getSheetByName(mainsheet);
  var value = targetSheet.getRange("C4").getValue();
   return value;;
   }
```

```html
  <html>
  <head>
  </head> 
  <body>
  <div style=" padding:10px; background-color:#ccebff">
   <form name="frm">
    <center><B>학생 정보</B> </center>
   
       
    <b>이름 </b>
    <input type="text" name="Name" ID="reginame" size="6" value=<?=Name()?>>
    
     <b>학번</b>
    <input type="text" name="Number" iD="reginum" size="4" value=<?=bb()?>>
   
    
    
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: About `What I want is to refresh or reload sidebar when I choose data on Cell C4 through drop-down.`, I think that this can be achieved. But from your question, I cannot understand about your goal. Can I ask you about how do you want to refresh or reload the sidebar? For example, can you explain about this by providing your current script?

Comment: You can rerun the dialog code and it will replace the current dialog and you can even change the content by using `$(function(){});` if you use JQuery or `window.onload` for straight javascript.

Comment: I added my script!

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the script. From your updated question, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to refresh the sidebar using the edited value of "C4", when the dropdown list of cell "C4" is changed.
- You want to achieve this by modifying your script.

In this answer, I would like to propose to use the installable OnEdit event trigger.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please add the following function to your script. And, [please install the OnEdit event trigger to the function of `inatalledOnEdit`.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

```
function inatalledOnEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "C4") {
    showsidbar();
  }
}
```

- When the dropdown list of the cell "C4" is changed, the function of `inatalledOnEdit` is run by the installable OnEdit event trigger. And, `showsidbar()` is run, and then, the sidebar is reopened, and the new value is set by `value=<?=Name()?>`.

#### Reference:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)